# How to shutil.copyfile only if file differ?

Tags: python, copy, shutil

`shutil.copyfile` is quite useful for copying files from a location to another. Unfortunately, it does copy the file even though it already exists.

I find `rsync --checksum` quite convenient in this case, but I don't think it worth calling `rsync` from Python.

What alternative can I use to copy a file only if it does not exist or it is not the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
import os
import filecmp
import shutil

if not os.path.exists(dst) or not filecmp.cmp(src, dst):
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```